# Create a nested list in Entity Framework query

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Problem description: I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Entity Framework Core to create a Web API.

I want to rewrite my Entity Framework query to output a list as a value of a key instead of a list of key/value pairs.

Expected outcome:

```
{
    "insertedAt": "2019-10-17T17:03:55.813",
    "country": "Germany",
    "forecastRun": "56F1D5B4-F0EF-11E9-8522-04D3B088DC49",
    "origin": "manual",
    "id": 68,
    "Timeseries": [
        {
                "timestamp": "2019-10-14T19:00:00", "value": 12
        },
        {
                "timestamp": "2019-10-14T20:00:00", "value": 10
        },
        {
                "timestamp": "2019-10-14T21:00:00", "value": 19
        }
    ]
}
```

Actual outcome:

```
[
    {
        "value": 0,
        "insertedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "country": null,
        "forecastRun": null,
        "origin": null,
        "id": 68,
        "Timeseries": []
    },
    {
        "value": 0,
        "insertedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "timestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "country": null,
        "forecastRun": null,
        "origin": null,
        "id": 69,
        "Timeseries": []
    }
    ...
]
```

As you can see not only does it now output the expected list of key/value pairs, but I also loose all other information.

What I have tried:

Models/ForecastModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tradingdata.Models
{
    public partial class ModelForecast
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ForecastRun { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Timeseries> MyTimestamps { get; set; }
        = new List<Timeseries>();
    }
    public partial class Timeseries
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controllers/ForecastController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using tradingdata.Models;

namespace tradingdata.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/forecasts")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly tradingdataContext _context;

        public ForecastController(tradingdataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetModelForecast([FromQuery] DateTime from, DateTime to, string model, string country)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var forecasts = await _context.ModelForecast
                                                    .Where(m => m.Timestamp >= from && m.Timestamp <= to && m.Country == country)
                                                    .ToListAsync();

            if (forecasts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(forecasts.Select(x => new ModelForecast
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                MyTimestamps = x.MyTimestamps.Select(z => new Timeseries
                {
                    Id = z.Id
                })
            })
             );
        }


    }
}
```

Thank you for your your help.

Comment: You are bind `ModelForecast` inside `MyTimestamps`?

Comment: I thought this would implicitly happen by defining a common field as in public int Id { get; set; }

Comment: You need to bind the child data either use `EntityFramework`

Comment: Alright, I will investigate that.